# Flask-RESTful getting 404 for endpoint if I don't put url parameter at the end

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

My endpoints:

```
# Routes
service.add_resource(UserRegister, "/register") # Works
service.add_resource(User, "/users/<int:user_id>") # Works
service.add_resource(CategoryListResource, "users/<int:user_id>/categories") # 404 not found
service.add_resource(CategoryResource, "/categories/<int:category_id>") # Works
service.add_resource(TaskListResource, "categories/<int:category_id>/tasks") # 404 not found
service.add_resource(TaskResource, "/tasks/<int:task_id>") # Works
```

My models are structured so that each user has some categories and each category has some tasks that belong to it. So I wanted my API to reflect that. When I want to GET all categories belonging to a user with `user_id = 3` I'd type `service/users/3/categories`, however this gives me a 404 not found:

```
"GET /service/users/3/categories HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

But when I change my endpoint to for example:

```
service.add_resource(CategoryListResource, "example/<int:user_id>") # Works fine now
```

This will work just fine, but it's not what I want, as it doesn't express the logic I mentioned earlier. Is there a way to have url parameters appear at the middle of an endpoint using Flask-RESTful or do I have to settle for a different approach?

P.S. `service` is the `url_prefix` of the Blueprint and it's not causing any problems, in fact all endpoints that have url parameters only at the end work just fine.

Comment: Try changing `users/<int:user_id>/categories` to `/users/<int:user_id>/categories`

Comment: @n1rna, thanks a bunch. I hadn't noticed that the `/` was missing at the beginning.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered.

Comment: @n1rna please type your comment as an answer so that I could accept it, I don't think it's possible to mark it as answered otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `users/<int:user_id>/categories` to `/users/<int:user_id>/categories`